# Jquery UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

Please let me know how to get the value of the first item in the list without it being selected?

Basically I type in some letters a few options come up but the user does not select or highlight them. I just want to capture the first option in the list and save that in a variable.

I would appreciate any help.

And yes I did have a look on the site first but did not spot the answer.

Many thanks

Comment: post the code you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery autocomplete generated list has class similar to `ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all`

`$('.ui-autocomplete li:first')`

will get you the first li

Comment: Hey Abdul,Many thanks for the help. I added .text to the end of that and it worked like a charm. Thanks a million for the help and apologies for the late response.